# I'm trying to merge two meshes and it's giving me these weird artifacts

Tags: mesh, boolean-modifier

[image: This is what it looks like when I try to merge them together. I've tried adding a face to the half sphere/nose for this model and also tried adding the modifier to the sphere/body instead and it gives more artifacts]

[image]

This is what it looks like when I try to merge them together. I've tried adding a face to the half sphere/nose for this model and also tried adding the modifier to the sphere/body instead and it gives more artifacts

Comment: it looks like you have 2 meshes or 2 objects overlapping

Comment: that's not the case though

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: this is my first time how do i do that?

Comment: @moonboots file added :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've given a *Boolean* modifier to the object called *Nose*, the mode of the *Boolean* is *Union*, which means that the final object will be the union of *Nose* and *Body*. The artefacts we see are the overlapping faces of the *Nose* object, as if it was already booleaned with *Body*, and the faces of *Body*. Apply the *Boolean* or hide the *Body* object and you won't have artefacts anymore. Also don't forget to apply the transforms of *Nose*.